# Get all list of possible filter criteria

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

From VBA I need to know the list of all **criteria** that I can choose in filtering columns. For example the following list: [1-ALFA;2-BETA;...5-ETC]

[image]

Comment: Do you want the **currently available criteria** or do you want **full criteria** assuming nothing else is filtered ??

Comment: I'm not sure, take this info with care, but I think what you see there is written from the `AutoFilter` method of the `Range` class at run-time. Which means, as far as I know, an object having the full list of available criteria as a property is never created - hence, you cannot get this list from it. In other words, you might have to implement your own `Loop` to create your own collection. But again, not sure, so let's wait a bit more before to write any code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we filter size for *large* and we want to list the criteria for column **A**:

```
Sub ShowCriteria()
    Dim r As Range, c1 As Collection, c2 As Collection
    Dim msg As String
    Set c1 = New Collection
    Set c2 = New Collection

    Dim LastRow As Integer

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Worksheets("sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With



    On Error Resume Next
    For Each r In Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        v = r.Value
        c1.Add v, CStr(v)
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            c2.Add v, CStr(v)
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    msg = "Full criteria"
    For i = 1 To c1.Count
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & c1.Item(i)
    Next i

    msg = msg & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Visible criteria"
    For i = 1 To c2.Count
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & c2.Item(i)
    Next i

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

Will display:

[image]

Comment: That's what I meant, I think the collection of criteria is not natively available and you need to build it up yourself starting from the data. But I think (probably for efficiency matters) OP wanted to know if they were stored somewhere as property of an existing object:

Comment: @MatteoNNZ  I think you are correct..............if I need to drive AutoFilter with VBA, I usually gather the criteria before applying any of those criteria.

Comment: @pnuts  You are correct!! .................I would also need something better than *MsgBox*