# Get all filter criteria in a column for a large WorkSheet

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am basically looking for an efficient version of this question and not a for loop through the entire column:
[Get all list of possible filter criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773987/get-all-list-of-possible-filter-criteria)

I have a worksheet like shown in the image (but much larger). I now would like to save all filter criteria (In this example: Text1, Text num 2) for the third column in a variable.

[image]

I tried something like this already:

```
Sub GetFilterCriteria()
' Activate filter mode
   With ActiveSheet
          .AutoFilterMode = False
          .Range("C2").AutoFilter ' The "Whatever" column
   End With
Dim f As filters
Set f = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.filters
myCriteria = f.Criteria1
```

I hoped to get an Array of all Criteria in the variable myCriteria, but it doesn't work. Can somebody help?

Comment: Load the data into a `Variant` array then use a `Scripting.Dictionary` to extract the unique values. Or you can use `WorksheetFunction.Unique` if your version of Excel supports it.

Comment: Nice idea. Do you mean: 
```Dim myColumn as Variant```
```myColumn = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C...").Value```

```Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary```

But how to get this into the Dictionary?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36044556/quicker-way-to-get-all-unique-values-of-a-column-in-vba

Comment: Wow, that's really helpful! Thank you so much BigBen!

Answer (score 1):

@BigBen answered this question in the comments. Let me share the detailed solution:

```
lastRow = Range(CStr("C" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

Dim data(), dict As Object, r As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

data = ActiveSheet.Range("C3", "C" & CStr(lastRow)).Columns(1).Value

For r = 1 To UBound(data)
    dict(data(r, 1)) = Empty
Next

data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys())
```

data contains all filter criteria you can select from the filter dropdown list once. For my list with row number ~35k it took less than 1s.